# Setting Properties on Variable Creation JS C#

Tags: javascript, c#, variables, properties

C# has a feature that we can set the class instance properties on the element creation (without a constructor). like this:

```cs
var Joe = new Person() {
    Age = 36,
    Weight = 83
}
```

Do we have a similar thing in JS and PHP?

JS something like:

```js
var ActionBox = document.createElement("div") {
    className: "ActionBox"
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). It copies the properties of the *source* object and assigns them to the *target* object and returns the modified target.

```js
var ActionBox = Object.assign(document.createElement("div"), {
    className: "ActionBox"
});

console.log(ActionBox);
```

Comment: Very well, is it performance-friendly?

Comment: @Movahhedi That question depends on what you're measuring against; there aren't any alternatives that allow this kind of syntax. But if you're curious you could always check how the benchmark holds up against looping over the object and manually assigning the properties. [benchmark](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/18194/0/objectassign-vs-polyfill)